# How to find the index position matched key in PHP multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array. i want to find the position of given key in that array.

my array

```
Array
(
    [200] => Array
        (
            [totalQuesAttempted] => 10
            [totalCorrectQuestion] => 2
        )

    [100] => Array
        (
            [totalQuesAttempted] => 10
            [totalCorrectQuestion] => 3
        )

    [400] => Array
        (
            [totalQuesAttempted] => 10
            [totalCorrectQuestion] => 4
        )

    [300] => Array
        (
            [totalQuesAttempted] => 10
            [totalCorrectQuestion] => 7
        )

    [500] => Array
        (
            [totalQuesAttempted] => 10
            [totalCorrectQuestion] => 8
        )

)
```

i am passing `UPID` value, and i need index position of that UPID.

```
$UPID = "300";
$result = array_search($UPID, array_values($usersAttemptsInfo));
```

my expected output is 3 because 300 index position is 3

Answer (score 1):

Everything is correct but instead of `array_values` use `array_keys`:

```
$UPID = "300";
$result = array_search($UPID, array_keys($usersAttemptsInfo)); 
echo $result;
```